# How to understand recursive Boundary conditions？

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree

Recently I have met a problem "Construct Tree from given Inorder and Preorder traversals".And I have look the source(by java).
[Construct Tree from given Inorder and Preorder traversals](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/)

But one point I am so confused in the code,that is  "if(inStrt > inEnd)
     return NULL;",I want to know how the author think out  this not obvious boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each recursive call of `buildTree()`, the inorder sequence denoted by `in[]` is effectively divided into two sub-sequences, one sub-sequence for nodes that belong to the left of the parent and the other sub-sequence for nodes that belong to the right of the parent. (The original sequence isn't physically divided, but rather, indices are passed into `buildTree()` to reflect the sub-sequences.)

As given in the example at the top of the linked page, `in = [D, B, E, A, F, C]`, and since `A` is root, `in_left = [D, B, E]` and `in_right = [F, C]`. Thus `inStr` and `inEnd` indices passed into `buildTree()` to reflect these sub-sequences would be `(0, 2)` and `(4, 5)`.

So what does it mean when `inStr > inEnd`? Simply put, there are no children nodes left, so we can stop there.

The "recursive boundary condition" is really very similar to that of Quicksort, where the low and high indices are compared.